# How to identify a travelling wave?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

I have the following equation: $u(x,t)= e^{-t} f(x-ct)$ . I have to figure out whether it is a traveling wave or not?  The amplitude of the wave in this case is time-dependent i.e. $e^{-t}$. Does it still qualify as a traveling wave even though it is not in the form $g(x-ct)$? Please suggest.

Comment: If I had to answer this, I would try to get as clear an idea of what the teacher or whoever wants.  These "Is this a ... ?" questions are often more questions of value -- what is important here? -- than of fact.  For my part, it definitely is "kin" to a traveling wave, but it doesn't strictly fit the definition you will find in a text book.  So if I had to give a yes/no, I would say no.

Answer (score 2):

The wave you write respects the identity:

$u(x,t)=u(x-vt,0)e^{-t}=u_0(x-vt)e^{-t}$

where I called $u_0(x)=u(x,0)$ the wave at time $0$.

The wave at time $t$ can be obtained by the wave at time $t=0$ first translating $u_0$ by a distance $vt$, an operation that does not change its shape, and than multiplying by a uniform decaying factor $e^{-t}$ that does not change the shape but brings the amplitude to zero.

If we made a video, this wave would vanish over time. I would leave to other users/formal books to define whether this is a travelling wave or not, even if in my opinion it is not.

Comment: Are you saying a wave that travels cannot decay? You are confusing traveling wave with *periodic* traveling wave. Not all waves are defined by *the* wave equation, there are many such wave equations that exhibit wave behavior.

Comment: @Ninad Munshi Then can it be considered as a travelling wave?

Comment: I expanded my answer. In my opinion a "travelling wave" whose power decreases exponentially with time is not a travelling wave, even if its shape is preserved.

Comment: @Harveer you should listen to Bob. Without knowing what you've been studying and what your teachers intent was (understanding traveling waves vs recognizing what is or isn't a solution to the simple linear wave equation) no one can give you a definite answer. Ultimately I think the teacher would be doing you a disservice by confusing traveling wave solutions of the wave equation with traveling waves in general, but sometimes these simplifications need to happen to teach effectively.

Comment: @Thomas traveling waves in general are defined by the actions of compactly supported solutions, not any of the stuff you have written because what you quote is specific only to the simple linear wave equation.

Comment: @NinadMunshi apart from definitions, one should now *what* is happening. That is why my answer is not a yes/no question but I tried to discuss (up to my knowledge) what is going on

Comment: @NinadMunshi I still think that I wrote correct stuff. If you want to write formal definitions of travelling wave in a separate answer and give your contribution you are welcome to do that.

Comment: @NinadMunshi I followed anyway your suggestions. Maybe you know more than me what is the "accepted" definition of travelling wave and I encourage you to write a separate answer. I limited myself to write some observations that in my intuitive definition of travelling wave would lead me to say that the answer is that this is not a travelling wave.

Comment: @Thomas if you would like, I would be more than happy to discuss pde theory in chat. The more I think about it, the more I realize that formally discussing a traveling wave may be outside of OP's toolbox. If not, I can leave you with this thought experiment: Even with volume preserving waves, there's no reason to expect constant motion yet the $v$ here must remain fixed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127343/discussion-between-thomas-and-ninad-munshi).